# Can i fetch an URL and click button using PHP

Tags: php, scripting

I have a task that requires me to click on a lot of update buttons on some pages every day, i want to automate this by fetching those pages that have the buttons (in HTML form maybe!) and clicking them using only PHP/PHP Library, is this possible? so that in the end i will configure a cron that will do this for me every day, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Codeception would be great for that.

Here's the Quick Start Page: https://codeception.com/quickstart